# Finite Products and Coproducts coincide for Abelian Category.

Tags: abelian-categories, morphism

I am trying to prove that in an Abelian Category, the morphism $(\pi_A, \pi_B): A \sqcup B \rightarrow A \times B$ is an isomorphism so that finite Products and Coproducts coincide.

I know the proofs for Monomorphism and Epimorphism are going to be similar so I wanted to see if given the proof for Epic, I can figure out proof for Monic.

Edit: I have to prove by hand that this map is Epic

Comment: Are you attached to this idea of showing that map is a mono and an epi? There is a straightforward proof that holds even in additive categories, but of course the strategy is different since a mono-epi is not an iso in this setting.

Comment: Yes the problem asks us to show that the map is mono and epic by hand. Then, using this and induction, we have our desired result.